# Connect to google cloud VM by ssh

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a VM in Google Cloud. I added my public key by browser session into `.ssh/authorized_keys` folder (I have stable internet connection).

I am trying to connect to this machine from console as usual:

```
 ssh -v myname@ipaddress
```

I just see:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ipaddress [ipaddress] port 22.
```

And nothing happens. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: are you able to telnet the instance? like `#telnet ip_address 22`

Comment: Start the VM. Open the port in the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use public-key authentication for SSH, you can add that key as a metadata field in an instance or in a project. If you set it instance-level, you'll only be able to use that key on that specific instance; setting it project-wide enables its usage for all instances in that project.

Follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#edit-ssh-metadata) on how to set SSH public keys.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the public key on the meta data ssh key

Comment: This needs more explanation